# GCP: Authentication error 403 when sending a DELETE request via google cloud compute API

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, http-status-code-403

My problem is simple but I can't get my head around where is the problem. I am running a Docker image in a GCP compute instance that should self-destroy its own instance when the container has finished. The `main.py` script looks something like this:

```py
from google.cloud import compute


def main():
    '''main container function'''

def delete_instance():
    project_id = os.getenv('PROJECT_ID')
    zone = os.getenv('ZONE')
    zone = os.getenv('INSTANCE_NAME')
    instance = compute.InstancesClient()
    instance.delete(project=project_id, zone=zone, instance=instance)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    delete_instance()
```

`instance.delete()` returns a 403 error `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: ...`

My understanding is that it is failing to authenticate the request. This instance is using the default service account and has been granted (and enabled) permissions to delete an instance: `Compute Instance Admin (v1)`. I don't think I am missing any required arguments according to the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.instances.InstancesClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_instances_InstancesClient_delete). Finally, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.instances.InstancesClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_instances_InstancesClient) if one does not specify credentials the client will attempt to ascertain the credentials from the environment, which is the case here. Which as I understand means using the default service account credentials/token.

Am I using the `google-cloud-compute` library correctly? Has anyone ever experienced this? Thanks ahead

Comment: Yes, you're correct that Google libraries are able to automatically obtain credentials from the environment. In this case, a process (!) running on a Compute Engine VM will use the the Metadata service to acquire the creds of the Service Account (often default) that the instance is using. You're correct to add the IAM permissions. I suspect (!) that your issue is that the container is unable to access these credentials.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I think (!?) the solution is to identify the VM's identity and access the Metadata service directly to obtain a token. Although I've not tried this, see [`compute_engine.Credentials()`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guide.html#compute-engine-container-engine-and-the-app-engine-flexible-environment) this may work. I assume there's a "correct" solution to this problem as it's such an obvious need. One challenge is that ADC provides a "portable" solution and you don't want to break this with a proprietary fix.

Comment: Hmm that was a great idea but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Apologies! Can you shell into the VM and run a container e.g. Debian interactively? From that shell, can you access the Metadata service? From the host VM (!) and from containers running on it, can you `curl --header "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token`? This is what ADC should (!?) be doing.

Comment: By the way, when it's running a Google Cloud compute service such as Compute Engine, your code could get `PROJECT_ID`, `ZONE` and `INSTANCE_NAME` from the Metadata service too.

Comment: Thanks for the env vars tip from the metadata server. It is a nice hack to have around. Re what you suggest, I keep getting error 403 when I ssh into the machine, both inside and outside the container. Super weird

Comment: The credentials that your program is using do not have sufficient permission to delete the VM instance. A common problem is that the program is not using the credentials you think it is. As a test, create the **InstancesClient** by specifying a service instead of using ADC.

Comment: Can you also confirm the instance's Service Account's scopes (and email). `gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} --zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(service_accounts)"`. It will need `cloud-platform` or `compute` ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#compute))

Comment: Another common problem when running code on Compute Engine, is **scoped down** credentials. These are credentials with the correct IAM roles, but Compute Engine **Acces Scopes** are limiting permissions.

Comment: Thanks both for the help. @JohnHanley was right and the problem were the scopes. I figured out that when creating the instance google was adding these two scopes:  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly. That limited the permissions of the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the solution here for reference. The problem was that even with the right permissions, during instance creation these were scoped down automatically (not sure why). Adding this option to `gcloud compute instances create-from-container` fixed it:

```
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```